# How to echo a variable in a variable PHP

Tags: php

For some landing page templates there is code like this:

```
<?php
    $Name = 'FOO';
    $Title = 'FooTitle';
    $Date = '00/00/0000';
    $Time = '00:00';
    $Time2 = 'AM';
    $AttendLink = 'http://linktoattend.html';
    $LogoLink = 'http://www.google.com';
    $Logo = 'http://www.domain/images/image.jpg';
    $LWidth = '';
    $LHeight = '';
    $Event = '<p class="indent">foo</p>';
    $List = '<ul>
                 <li>One</li>
                 <li>Two</li>
                 <li>Three</li>
                 <li><strong class="red">As an added bonus:</strong>foo</li>
            </ul>';
    $Offer = '<p class="indent">foo</p>';
    $Presenter = '<p class="indent"><a href="<?php echo $Link ?>">Link!</a></p>';
?>
```

For brevity the area of concern is this

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $Title ?></title>
</head>

<body>
<p><?php echo $Presenter ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

where the variable "$Presenter" is outputting "" as the link. I understand why it's doing this but not how to fix it. How do I include a variable "$Link" inside another variable "$Presenter"? Is there a more semantically correct way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: How are the HTML and the PHP code connected? Are they in the same file?

Comment: You have to perform *string concatenation*.

Comment: @Pekka yes they are in same file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have nested `<?php ?>` tags.

Change to:

```
$Presenter = '<p class="indent"><a href="' . $Link . '">Link!</a></p>';
```

Or

```
$Presenter = "<p class='indent'><a href='$Link'>Link!</a></p>";
```

Comment: Thx Laxman13! Lots of good answers, I really appreciate everyone's help. Awesome community. I'm going to read up on string concatenation as Felix Kling suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$Presenter = '<p class="indent"><a href="'.$Link.'">Link!</a></p>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't reopen `<?php ?>` when you are already inside `<?php ?>`. Instead concatenate the variable into a single-quoted string:

```
$Presenter = '<p class="indent"><a href="' . $Link . '">Link!</a></p>';
```

Or, reverse your quotes to use double on the outside, and interpolate the variable inside.  Within double-quotes, variables encountered will be interpolated. If it's a complex variable, like an array `$var[1]` or object `$obj->property`, enclose them in `{}` like `{$object->property}`.

```
$Presenter = "<p class='indent'><a href='$Link'>Link!</a></p>";
```

You really should review the [PHP Strings documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php) for details on how these are to be used.

Answer (score 1):

I can just recommend reading about "**printf**":

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php

that way you can "include" another variable inside the other string.

So you can have your config-file (with the template content), and a templatefile, where the printf takes place.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see stated where the variable $Link is defined, but I would say, if it is defined before your invoke your template at all, use:

```
<?php
    $Presenter = '<p class="indent"><a href="'.$Link.'">Link!</a></p>';
?>
```

If it gets defined between that variable pool definition and the markup generation, do a good old placeholder search/replace:

```
<?php
   $Presenter = '<p class="indent"><a href="{{link}}">Link!</a></p>';
?>
```

and then

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $Title ?></title>
</head>

<body>
<p><?php echo str_replace('{{link}}', $Link, $Presenter); ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

note: I assume your $Link variable is clean to be injected in markup directly